# How to properly use pjax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, pjax

I have a very sketchy idea of how pjax works and therefore a very sketchy implementation of it on my site. I have this code at the beginning of all my jquery

`$('li a').pjax('#container');`

and the thing that you would click looks like this

`<li><a href="main.html"><div id="sortmain" class="catagories">main</div></a></li>`

so when I click that `li` it loads the main.html into the container div. But it is glitchy and pretty slow. How can I improve this? Also, because main.html is a real document when I refresh the page it only shows what main.html outputs, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell why it is slow or glitchy without looking at your site.

If you want `main.html` to be a full-page (so that refresh works without server-side processing) you can use the fragment option in pjax:

```
$('li a').pjax("#container", { fragment: "#container" });
```

This will update the `#container` div with PJAX (if pushState is available) and on older browsers your site will just work the way it used to.